# Calculate text size according to width of text area

Tags: android, textview

I have a text that should be set to TextView with specified width. It needs to calculate the text size to fit it into TextView.

In other words: Is there a way to fit text into TextView area, like the ImageView scale type feature?

Comment: Check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259016/scale-text-in-a-view-to-fit/7259136#7259136

Answer (score 36):

This should be a simple solution:

```
public void correctWidth(TextView textView, int desiredWidth)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    paint.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface());
    float textSize = textView.getTextSize();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    while (bounds.width() > desiredWidth)
    {
        textSize--;
        paint.setTextSize(textSize);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    }

    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
}
```

Comment: what is desired width? I need to match_parent

Comment: BTW you can get a paint directly from `textView`

Comment: This solution doesn't take in account potential desiredWidth grow (if it grows, textSize won't change)

Answer (score 29):

If it is the Size of the space the Text takes your after then the following might help:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect bounds = new Rect();

int text_height = 0;
int text_width = 0;

paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);// your preference here
paint.setTextSize(25);// have this the same as your text size

String text = "Some random text";

paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

text_height =  bounds.height();
text_width =  bounds.width();
```

Edit (after comment):
Use the above in reverse:

```
int text_height = 50;
int text_width = 200;

int text_check_w = 0;
int text_check_h = 0;

int incr_text_size = 1;
boolean found_desired_size = true;

while (found_desired_size){
    paint.setTextSize(incr_text_size);// have this the same as your text size

    String text = "Some random text";

    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    text_check_h =  bounds.height();
    text_check_w =  bounds.width();
    incr_text_size++;

if (text_height == text_check_h && text_width == text_check_w){
found_desired_size = false;
}
}
return incr_text_size; // this will be desired text size from bounds you already have
```

//this method may be tweaked a bit, but gives you an idea on what you can do

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. I don't need to calculate the text height/width according to text size and font. I need to calculate the text size according to height/width and font.

Comment: @kankan :  didi you get answer ?

Answer (score 13):

```
 public static float getFitTextSize(TextPaint paint, float width, String text) {
     float nowWidth = paint.measureText(text);
     float newSize = (float) width / nowWidth * paint.getTextSize();
     return newSize;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your code so that the asker understands your solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. The fastest and the simplest.

Comment: Simple and fast

Comment: When and where do you call this?  `onCreate()` is too soon as most Views aren't ready yet.  Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @ScottBiggs you can call it inside view.post(), it's called when view is ready to draw

Answer (score 3):

I needed one that calculates best fit for both width and height, in pixels. This is my solution:

```
private static int getFitTextSize(Paint paint, int width, int height, String text) {
   int maxSizeToFitWidth = (int)((float)width / paint.measureText(text) * paint.getTextSize());
   return Math.min(maxSizeToFitWidth, height);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had to face the same problem when having to ensure that text fits into a specific box. The following is the best performing and most accurate solution that I have for it at the moment:

```
/**
 * A paint that has utilities dealing with painting text.
 * @author <a href="maillto:nospam">Ben Barkay</a>
 * @version 10, Aug 2014
 */
public class TextPaint extends android.text.TextPaint {
    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code TextPaint}.
     */
    public TextPaint() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code TextPaint} using the specified flags
     * @param flags
     */
    public TextPaint(int flags) {
        super(flags);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new {@code TextPaint} copying the specified {@code source} state.
     * @param source The source paint to copy state from.
     */
    public TextPaint(Paint source) {
        super(source);
    }

    // Some more utility methods...

    /**
     * Calibrates this paint's text-size to fit the specified text within the specified width.
     * @param text      The text to calibrate for.
     * @param boxWidth  The width of the space in which the text has to fit.
     */
    public void calibrateTextSize(String text, float boxWidth) {
        calibrateTextSize(text, 0, Float.MAX_VALUE, boxWidth);
    }

    /**
     * Calibrates this paint's text-size to fit the specified text within the specified width.
     * @param text      The text to calibrate for.
     * @param min       The minimum text size to use.
     * @param max       The maximum text size to use.
     * @param boxWidth  The width of the space in which the text has to fit.
     */
    public void calibrateTextSize(String text, float min, float max, float boxWidth) {
        setTextSize(10);
        setTextSize(Math.max(Math.min((boxWidth/measureText(text))*10, max), min));
    }
}
```

This simply calculates the correct size rather than running a trial/error test.

You can use it like this:

```
float availableWidth = ...; // use your text view's width, or any other width.
String text = "Hi there";
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setTypeface(...);
paint.calibrateTextSize(text, availableWidth);
```

---

Or otherwise, without the extra type:

```
/**
 * Calibrates this paint's text-size to fit the specified text within the specified width.
 * @param paint     The paint to calibrate.
 * @param text      The text to calibrate for.
 * @param min       The minimum text size to use.
 * @param max       The maximum text size to use.
 * @param boxWidth  The width of the space in which the text has to fit.
 */
public static void calibrateTextSize(Paint paint, String text, float min, float max, float boxWidth) {
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    paint.setTextSize(Math.max(Math.min((boxWidth/paint.measureText(text))*10, max), min));
}
```

Use like so:

```
float availableWidth = ...; // use your text view's width, or any other width.
String text = "Hi there";
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setTypeface(...);
calibrateTextSize(paint, text, 0, Float.MAX_VALUE, availableWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in Kotlin takes into account both width growth and reduction:

```
    private fun TextView.updateTextSize(desiredTextViewWidth: Int, text: String) {
        var lastFitSize = 0f
        var foundMaxSize = false

        while (!foundMaxSize && lastFitSize < Float.MAX_VALUE) {
            paint.textSize = lastFitSize + 1

            foundMaxSize = paint.measureText(text) > desiredTextViewWidth
            if (!foundMaxSize) {
                lastFitSize = paint.textSize
            }
        }

        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, lastFitSize)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a new API for text auto sizing

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    pp:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"       
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp".     
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

**Note**: If you use `autosizing`, it is **not** recommended to use the value `"wrap_content"` for the `layout_width` or `layout_height` attributes