# Don't you think the resources to learn Android development for an amateur programmer are insufficient OR incomplete?

Tags: android-2.2-froyo, android

I know there are a lot of books, and lot of stuff at developer.google.com, but the example codes in almost all the books and at Google's site just start using various predefined classes out of the blue without a proper explanation of the methods being called.
And even when you check the docs, most of the times you can't be sure what exactly the method does.
The docs almost feel like a Wikipedia of classes, with one class linking to another couple of ones, which seems kind of recursive.
So how exactly is one supposed to learn Android dev?

Comment: Learn by doing, not by reading.

Comment: @Popmpe There has to be a minimal level of reading first especially when dealing with huge SDKs.

Comment: @Peter.R: Yeah, this is mostly a personal preference. What I shortly meant was to combine the two things and not only read and hope to understand the whole concept directly.

Answer (score 1):

Start with learning about OOP, and then dive into java. Once you've got a hold on that, hop into Android and start mucking about. I learned quite a bit just from reading stackoverflow, the dev guide, and googling around. If you want to know how to do something, try some stuff out. If you can't figure it out, ask here.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're a beginner programmer, then the terseness and dryness of the material can be quite discouraging. Most people learn Android through trial-and-error, using the books, online materials, and this site as guides.

At the end of the day Android is just a tool, so in order to understand it (and therefore use it correctly) you need a firm grounding in the theory behind why it was designed the way it was. For this you need to understand things like Object Oriented Design, UI programming, concurrency, data modeling, etc. Also, read [Framework Topics](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) on the developer site as it describes the fundamentals of the platform and the design decisions that govern its use.

Once you have a good grasp of these concepts, everything else just becomes memorization (i.e., what class do I use to do task x). At this level, the best way to learn is by picking a project and just tinkering away using all the resources at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they are easy to use, easy to read, some are more difficult than others, but they also provide code samples and enough information for developpers to start with.

If you don't know how to implement methods, read them, or can't read the docs at all, I suggest you start learning the Java language first as a basis to the Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the API docs are a bit dry but there are a lot of good resources on the net. Here are some links to them:

[Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area)

[AndDev](http://www.anddev.org/)

There are many more - try adding 'using' or 'tutorial' in your Google searches. Also, keep stackoverflow bookmarked - it's pretty good too!

Comment: I have StackOverflow as a pinned tab in my firefox at work. I always have it up!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have been a professionel programmer for 20+ years I found it difficult to get started with Android because I never had done anything in Java and even didn't know Eclipse which is somewhat strange to get started with (although I like it quite much now).

I am the type who prefers a good old paper book, so I bought *Professional Android 2 Application Development* from Wrox. To be honest, I found the book intimidating as it started "using classes out of the blue" as you describe it, and on a very high level.

Then I found *Android Application Development For Dummies*. I never thought I would by a "dummies" book, but it is actually very, very good and highly recommended. It starts gently on a need-know-basis, ie. it doesn't tell you tons of hard-to-understand techinal stuff you don't need to get started. It tells you when you need it - if it tells you at all, because you are not supposed to stay with that book forever. You will outgrow it after a while, but *when* you do, you are well equipped.