# How to get max lines of Text

Tags: android, text, textview, line

How to get the maximum number of lines that can be written in TextView? I tried this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
getWindowManager (). getDefaultDisplay (). getMetrics (metrics);
float width = metrics.widthPixels;
float height = metrics.heightPixels;

int lines = (int) (height / textView.getLineHeight ());

System.out.println (lines);
```

However, this variant gives the wrong information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> textview.getLineCount()

It's all in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29)

**EDIT:** I was a bit too fast. I assume you want the number of lines that CAN be inside a textview instead of how many there currently ARE in the textview... In that case -> have a look at this question: [Calculate text size according to width of text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area)

Answer (score 1):

**textview.getLineCount() will help you**

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.getHeight() / textView.getLineHeight()
```

`textView.getHeight()` and `textView.getLineHeight()` both will consider the height on the screen with the screen dpi.

Here is the post to get the correct height of view.
[View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0/24035591#24035591)