# How to set the width for text in canvas method in android?

Tags: android, canvas

In my application I used canvas to draw the text. now I want to set the width of the draw text. I can set only `x` , `y` position. I can't set width and height.

**My problem**

**update**
 for example "India is my Country" or if any  length text it goes outside of canvas that is outside of the background image.
i want to print "India is

my country" if i set width mean i think it goes to next line

```
 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas1)
{
Paint paint = new Paint();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ban_background);
        Bitmap resizeImage1=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,590,350,false);
        canvas1.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas1.drawBitmap(resizeImage1,10,5, null);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        canvas1.drawText(CameraText, 100,175, paint);
        }
         }
```

Comment: when you are setting the text size width and height will be automatically set, i dont think u can explicitly set the width and height. But if u could explain wot is ur real problem is i can help you. You can get the height and width of the text after setting text size like this  Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

Comment: update mt problem rajesh

Comment: hope this is what you want refer my answer bro if not sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used to create a bitmap as follows and iam able to set the width and height

```
 Bitmap finalImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Bitmap tempImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, IMAGE_HEIGHT,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas g = new Canvas(finalImage);
    Canvas gtemp = new Canvas(tempImage);
    g.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    gtemp.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint pnt = new Paint();
    pnt.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    pnt.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    pnt.setTextSize(40);
    pnt.setTypeface(font1);

    g.drawText(input, IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, 40, pnt);
    Rect grct = new Rect(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    Rect grctTemp = new Rect(0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    gtemp.drawBitmap(finalImage, grct, grctTemp, pnt);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you mean but you can try the setStrokeWidth(2.0f)

i hope this helps :D

Comment: i am guessing you know the x and y of the location of the text. Just measure the length of the text which you can do by using this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area) and then see if the x + width is beyond the scope of the canvas, then just cut the string into two and print like that (probably using some sort of recursion)

something like (x+textWidth > canvas.width) then go ahead and cut the text