# Adapt text size depending on the size of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview

I have 4 TextViews placed horizontally filling all the width of the screen, and each TextView with the same horizontal width . Depending on the device's screen the total width is diferent. I want to change the textsize to fill each TextView horizontally but in a manner that the text fits. Is there any way to do this?? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this link could help you immensly as it is very similar.  You may have to SET your widths static based upon you screen width then continue to adjust your font size until the vertical direction fits for each textview.

[Calculate text size according to width of text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area)