# Android: Textview show specific number of lines and click button to view next number of lines

Tags: java, android

I have a `TextView` that shows 7 lines at a time. I am trying to put an icon below the `TextView`, so that if I click the icon, the next 7 lines will appear if there are more lines.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="7"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/curl"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/curl"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_scrollD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvmsg"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_24" />
```

Can anybody help in this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing something similar to "Show more" option used frequently. This exact problem is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675331/add-view-more-at-the-end-of-textview-after-3-lines).

use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to show "Show more" and "Show less" strings (the text under textView you are talking about. Please refer to the answer for more details.