# Losing HTML format when using read more and read less functionality implement on Textview in android

Tags: android, html, formatting, format, android-styles

I used custom read more and read less functionality on textview but all Html tag are not working and convert to paragraph.

[Add "View More" at the end of textview after 3 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675331/add-view-more-at-the-end-of-textview-after-3-lines)

mytxt_hpofferdetails.setText(Html.fromHtml(s,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));

makeTextViewResizable(mytxt_hpofferdetails, 3, "Read More", true);

Comment: And how we can guess what your problem is? without looking the code

Comment: what you tried please post

Comment: I have HTML string and display in Textview it's working fine but I want to implement more functionality like "ReadMore" and "ReadLess"  in the same Textview that time all string display like a paragraph. 

"<ol><li>Get 15% off on OPD consultation. <\/li><li>Get 10% off on Lab & Radiology tests. <\/li><li>Get 10% off on In patient billings. <\/li><li>Get 20% off on Health check-up packages.<\/li><\/ol>"

Comment: Add relevant code what you have done to achieve your Read More and Read Less functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675331/add-view-more-at-the-end-of-textview-after-3-lines


I followed the above method for "ReadMore" and "ReadLess" using HTML formate

 mytxt_hpofferdetails.setText(Html.fromHtml(s,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));



makeTextViewResizable(mytxt_hpofferdetails, 3, "Read More", true);